# Create symlink to other paths from babun home directory

Tags: windows, zsh, symlink

I just installed [babun](https://github.com/babun/babun) on my Windows 7.

babun's `~/home/xxx` is located at `C:\Users\Admin\.babun\cygwin\home\xxx` on windows file system.

> xxx is my user name on windows

Let's say my worked files are stored in `D:\work`, how can I create symlink to link to `D:\work`?, so I can easily use `cd mysymlink` to change the working directory from babun's home directory.

Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create a link in `/` like this:

```
ln -s /cygdrive/d/work /myworkdir
```

Then you should be able to `cd /myworkdir`  to your disired directory.

Another option would be to create an alias in your .bashrc:

```
echo "alias gtw=\"cd /cygdrive/d/work\"" >> ~/.bashrc
```

After that you could simply write `gtw`.

Note: gtw means **g**o **t**o **w**ork :) but you can choose whatever you like...

**Edit:** Oh, sorry you added the zsh tag, I didnt see then the second option must be like this:

```
echo "alias gtw=\"cd /cygdrive/d/work\"" >> ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: I will let you know further feedback after testing, thanks so much